# Google Interview : Find Crazy Distance Between Strings

Tags: string, algorithm

This Question was asked to me at the Google interview. I could do it O(n*n) ... Can I do it in  better time. 
A string can be formed only by 1 and 0.

Definition:

X & Y are strings formed by 0 or 1

`D(X,Y)` = Remove the things common at the start from both X & Y. Then add the remaining lengths from both the strings.

For e.g.

`D(1111, 1000)` = Only First alphabet is common. So the remaining string is `111` & `000`. Therefore the result `length("111")` & `length("000")` = 3 + 3 = 6

`D(101, 1100)` = Only First two alphabets are common. So the remaining string is `01` & `100`. Therefore the result `length("01")` & `length("100")` = 2 + 3 = 5

It is pretty that obvious that do find out such a crazy distance is going to be linear. O(m).

Now the question is

given n input, say like

```
1111
1000
101
1100
```

Find out the maximum crazy distance possible.

n is the number of input strings.
m is the max length of any input string.

The solution of O(n<sup>2</sup> * m) is pretty simple. Can it be done in a better way?
Let's assume that m is fixed. Can we do this in better than O(n^2) ?

Comment: I was thinking that I can sort all of them. But even then i am not able proceed anywhere. Can anyone please guide me with the approach to this problem.

Comment: @Dukeling : Thanks for editing. Is it possible for you help me with the approach.

Comment: Then sorting will be part of the algorithm too. If list is sorted then just check consecutive elements for crazy distance & the hence maximum. However, I don't think sorting is the only way.

Comment: DoSparKot, counter-example to what you propose: what about "000", "001", "0010"? Sorting them lexicographically, and then checking the distance between consecutive elements, give D(000, 001) = len("0") + len("1") = 2, D(001, 0010) = len("") + len("0") = 1, but D(000, 0010) = len("0") + len("10") = 3.

Comment: Was there any maximum length(not count) of such strings specified?

Comment: Over here I am referring to 'n' as the number of strings. To find out the maximum crazy distance, I will have to compare it with the remaining n-1 strings. Therefore, the complexity is going to O(n^2)

Comment: Yes. Sorting them lexicographically is not going to work either here. I am pretty surprised as to how come a solution less than O(n^2) was expected out of me.

Comment: Wait a second. Your "brute force" solution to the problem "n string with lengths up to m" requires you to calculate the distance between each pair of strings. For any pair, it takes time O(m). You have O(n^2) such pairs. Therefore, the complexity is not even O(m*n) or O(n^2), it is O(m*n^2)!

Comment: how to exploit the nature of the strings here? O(n^2) or O(m*n^2) may be acceptable for arbitrary strings.

Comment: It seemed to me as if the interviewer was pretty certain that something better than O(n^2) exists. But I just could not figure that out.

Comment: Can you add the definition of crazy-distance to the question?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put the strings into a tree, where 0 means go left and 1 means go right. So for example

```
1111
1000
101
1100
```

would result in a tree like

```
        Root
             1
          0     1
         0 1*  0  1
        0*    0*    1*
```

where the * means that an element ends there. Constructing this tree clearly takes `O(n m)`.

Now we have to find the [diameter of the tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/) (the longest path between two nodes, which is the same thing as the "crazy distance"). The optimized algorithm presented there hits each node in the tree once. There are at most `min(n m, 2^m)` such nodes.

So if `n m < 2^m`, then the the algorithm is `O(n m)`.

If `n m > 2^m` (and we necessarily have repeated inputs), then the algorithm is still `O(n m)` from the first step.

This also works for strings with a general alphabet; for an alphabet with `k` letters build a `k`-ary tree, in which case the runtime is still O(n m) by the same reasoning, though it takes `k` times as much memory.

Comment: Looks like you coded 110 instead of 1100. Anyways, great solution. +1

Comment: I have a doubt. How can you guarantee that Diameter of the tree will be the crazy distance? Because we are deleting the Prefix from the tree. So, that changes the dynamics.

Comment: But that's exactly what the crazy distance is: after considering the common prefix, how long is each string? The common prefix is the common ancestor of the two strings in the tree, and their lengths after that deletion is the same thing as their depth in the tree below the common ancestor.

Comment: Just curious, did you encounter this problem elsewhere before or did this solution just came up in your head? Just trying to understand the reasoning on how you came up with this answer... I know it works, but for the life of me, I couldn't come up with this.. did stuff like sorting, XOR operations, scanning, simplfying the problem to make it equal length strings, etc.

Comment: @HenleyChiu No, I just thought of it. I don't remember my exact reasoning process, since this was five months ago, but my guess is that maybe the "maximum distane possible" part made me think "diameter of a graph", and then when i was thinking about how to make it a graph I realized it could just be a tree. I definitely didn't already know the diameter of a tree algorithm and just googled that though.

Comment: @Dougal i know this is an old answer, but i was just looking at it and im wondering, in this example every string started with a "1", but what if some strings started with "0" and some with "1" how would you build your tree? Specifically the "root" node.

Comment: @StanR. In this example, the root node has only one child, going right to 1. If something started with a 0, it'd have another child going left to 0.

Comment: @Dougal for D(1111, 1000), the length is 6 `length("111") & length("000") = 3 + 3 = 6`, but the diameter of that tree will be 7. So should we say the result is the the diameter of the tree minus 1?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is possible in O(nm) time by creating a binary tree where each bit in a string encodes the path (0 left, 1 right). Then finding the maximum distance between nodes of the tree [which can be done in O(n) time](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/).

Comment: I'm always surprised when a question's been up for an hour and then two people post the exact same answer within 30 seconds of each other... :)

Comment: LOL... Even i too was surprised...
Thanks guys. I knew this Diameter thing. But I could not apply it.. :( :( ... Thanks guys.

Comment: I have a doubt. How can you guarantee that Diameter of the tree will be the crazy distance? Because we are deleting the Prefix from the tree. So, that changes the dynamics.

Comment: @user1540945, if the strings have common prefixes then they will branch out at the point where they differ. So, the distance between them will not contain the common prefix.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, I think it works:

1. Create a binary tree from all strings. The tree will be constructed in this way: 
   at every round, select a string and add it to the tree. so for your example, the tree will be:

   ```
                     <root>
             <1>            <empty>
    <1>            <0>
   ```

   <1>   <0>     <1>     <0> 
   <1>       <0>              <0>

So each path from root to a leaf will represent a string.

1. Now the distance between each two leaves is the distance between two strings. To find the crazy distance, you must find the diameter of this graph, that you can do it easily by dfs or bfs.

The total complexity of this algorithm is:
O(n*m) + O(n*m) = O(n*m).

Comment: See the link in the answers by perreal and me for an O(n) algorithm to find the diameter. Doesn't change the overall runtime though.

Comment: on the link, n is the number of nodes so here we have n*m nodes. is that right ? or I'm wrong ? (thanks in advance)

Comment: Hmm - yeah, you're right, it needs to hit each node in the tree, for O(n m). Well, technically it's O(n m'), where m' is the mean length (rather than the max length), but so is the tree construction step.

Comment: thank you. m*n is the worst case but in average you are right.

Comment: Actually, no, it's not quite either of those things. The number of nodes in the tree is upper-bounded by min(n m, 2^m).

Comment: What do you mean by Prefix ?? if you mean common things at the start, there is no problem with the tree, common nodes for two strings just represent common things at the first of both strings not at the middle or end.

Answer (score 0):

To get an answer in O(nm) just iterate across the characters of all string (this is an O(n) operation).  We will compare at most m characters, so this will be done O(m).  This gives a total of O(nm).  Here's a C++ solution:

```
int max_distance(char** strings, int numstrings, int &distance) {
    distance = 0;
    // loop O(n) for initialization
    for (int i=0; i<numstrings; i++) 
        distance += strlen(strings[i]);

    int max_prefix = 0;
    bool done = false;
    // loop max O(m)
    while (!done) {
        int c = -1;
        // loop O(n)
        for (int i=0; i<numstrings; i++) {
            if (strings[i][max_prefix] == 0) {
                done = true; // it is enough to reach the end of one string to be done
                break;  
            }

            int new_element = strings[i][max_prefix] - '0';
            if (-1 == c)
                c = new_element;
            else {
                if (c != new_element) {
                    done = true;    // mismatch
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!done) {
            max_prefix++;
            distance -= numstrings;
        }
    }

    return max_prefix;
}


void test_misc() {
    char* strings[] = { 
        "10100",
        "10101110",
        "101011",
        "101"
    };

    std::cout << std::endl;
    int distance = 0;
    std::cout << "max_prefix = " << max_distance(strings, sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0]), distance) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is something like "find prefix for two strings", you can use trie(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to accerlate searching

I have a google phone interview 3 days before, but maybe I failed...

Best luck to you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why use trees when iteration gives you the same big O computational complexity without the code complexity. anyway here is my version of it in javascript  O(mn)

```
var len = process.argv.length -2; // in node first 2 arguments are node and program file
var input = process.argv.splice(2);
var current;
var currentCount = 0;
var currentCharLoc = 0;
var totalCount = 0;
var totalComplete = 0;
var same = true;
while ( totalComplete < len ) {
        current = null;
        currentCount = 0;
        for ( var loc = 0 ; loc < len ; loc++) {
                if ( input[loc].length === currentCharLoc) {
                        totalComplete++;
                        same = false;
                } else if (input[loc].length > currentCharLoc) {
                        currentCount++;
                        if (same) {
                                if ( current === null ) {
                                        current = input[loc][currentCharLoc];
                                } else {
                                        if (current !== input[loc][currentCharLoc]) {
                                                same = false;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        if (!same) {
                totalCount += currentCount;
        }
        currentCharLoc++;
}

console.log(totalCount);
```